# Sending email with Python script Output and using crontab to send weekly

Tags: python, linux, macos, cron

I have a Python script and I am trying to write a crontab and have the output from the Python script to be outputed to a file which then sends that output to an email address (to the body of the email not the title) that is specified. My system details and crontab entry is below:

```
System details:
Python: 2.7
OSX : 10.11


host$ crontab -l
11 11 13 10 4 2016 python pythonscript.py >> weekly.log | mail -s weekly.log     myemail@.com
```

Although when the crontab executes, the email sends me an email message with the subject line saying "weekly.log" with no body.

I have also tried crontab with below settings:

```
07 22 13 10 4 2016 /root/python/osversion_weekly.py | tee   /root/python/osversion`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log | mailx -s "OSLEVEL Report" mymail@server.com
```

Although I only get an email with Title "OSLEVEL Report" with an empty body

Update:
The error I seem to be getting from /var/log/cron is showing "orphan no passwd entry." Not quite sure what does means, and I havent seen any answers online to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` makes the python output get appended to the file `weekly.log`, after that no input is pushed forward to `mail`.

You could remove `>> weekly.log` and not have a log file or use the program `tee` in the pipe. `tee` writes to standard output and a file.

Like this:
`python pythonscript.py | tee -a weekly.log | mail -s weekly.log myemail@.com`

Comment: I tried this but the email I am getting is still a title with "weekly.log" and an empty body in the email

Comment: Did you check that the python script actually outputs stuff? ie. that the logfile not is empty. If your script only outputs error messages those wont get mailed or logged with your current setup.

Comment: Yeah the script works when i run it manually, ive tested it multiple times